# Common.py at Kiwi. How to mount to docker

Tags: docker, testing, kiwi-tcms

I followed this [Kiwi TCMS](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) step, but what is really for me to is to understand how do you mount the `common.py`(main configuration file) to the working kiwi instance.

I don't see the place of  `common.py` in the kiwi, so  I dunno where to mount it? Or do I have to recreate the images every time to get the new settings?

EDIT: 
I've tried [Kiwi TCMS configuration settings](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) guide and I changed some settings in `tcms/settings/common.py`

How to implement that setting in the working Kiwi environment?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The config file approach

The `common.py` file it seems to be located at `tcms/settings/common.py` as per your [second link](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)

> All sensible settings are defined in tcms/settings/common.py. You will have to update some of them for your particular production environment.

If you really want to map only this file then from the root of your proeject:

```
docker run -v ./tcms/settings/common.py:/absolute/container/path/to/tcms/settings/common.py [other-options-here] image-name
```

Running the docker command with the above volume map will replace the file inside the docker container `/absolute/container/path/to/tcms/settings/common.py` with the one in the host `tcms/settings/common.py`, thus the application will run with the settings defined in the host.

If you don't know the full path to `tcms/settings/common.py` inside the docker container, then you need to add the Dockerfile to your question so that we can help further.

## The ENV file approach

If not already existing a `.env` file in the root of your project create one and add there all env variables in the `common.py`:

`.env` example:

```
KIWI_DB_NAME=my_db_name
KIWI_DB_USER=my_db_user
KIWI_DB_PASSWORD=my_db_password
KIWI_DB_HOST=my_db_host
KIWI_DB_PORT=my_db_port
```

Add as many environment variables to the `.env` file as the ones you find in the python code that you want to customize.

Start the docker container from the place where the `.env` file is with the flag `--env-file .env`, something like:

```
docker run --env-file .env  [other-options-here] image-name
```

Comment: After I map this common.py file, in the docker running image. Wil it use it settings here :

Comment: After I map this common.py file, in the docker running image. Wil it use it settings there in /absolute/container/path/to/tcms/settings/common.py. I just want to run the config of common.py in the running container. Do I need to mount it specifically there? I want to specify e-mail SMTP client. I can't do  that I quess as an ENV